# error XA2006 with IAuthenticationHandler when linking

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm encountering this exception when linking to SDK assemblies and building the project:

`Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Could not resolve reference to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.Authentication.IAuthenticationHandler' (defined in assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60') with scope 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. When the scope is different from the defining assembly, it usually means that the type is forwarded.`

I've added Signalr.Client v. 3.1.2 for using Signalr in Xamarin.

Here's the PCL csproj:

```
<PackageReference Include="Fody" Version="6.1.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Forms.Controls.FlexButton" Version="0.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Push" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.XSnack" Version="1.0.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="PropertyChanged.Fody" Version="3.2.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Rg.Plugins.Popup" Version="1.2.0.223" />
    <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.6.292" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Media" Version="4.0.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamanimation" Version="1.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading" Version="2.4.11.982" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms" Version="2.4.11.982" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Transformations" Version="2.4.11.982" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.5.0.356" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms.RangeSlider" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material" Version="4.5.0.356" />
    <PackageReference Include="XamForms.HtmlLabel" Version="1.0.0" />
```

and here's the Xamarin Android csproj:

```
<PackageReference Include="Forms.Controls.FlexButton">
      <Version>0.11.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter">
      <Version>3.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics">
      <Version>3.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes">
      <Version>3.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Push">
      <Version>3.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Rg.Plugins.Popup">
      <Version>1.2.0.223</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Media">
      <Version>4.0.1.5</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamanimation">
      <Version>1.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading">
      <Version>2.4.11.982</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms">
      <Version>2.4.11.982</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Transformations">
      <Version>2.4.11.982</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.5.0.356" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" Version="28.0.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms.RangeSlider">
      <Version>1.0.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material">
      <Version>4.5.0.356</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="XamForms.HtmlLabel">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
```

The project.assets.json file has two dependencies on older version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/2.2.0": {
  "type": "package",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features": "2.2.0",
    "System.Text.Encodings.Web": "4.5.0"
  },
  "compile": {
    "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll": {}
  },
  "runtime": {
    "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll": {}
  }
},
```

and

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions/2.2.0": {
  "type": "package",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features": "2.2.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions": "2.2.0"
  },
  "compile": {
    "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll": {}
  },
  "runtime": {
    "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll": {}
  }
},
```

All others refer to 3.1.2 version.

Please help me on whether I should use any other versions of the packages, or maybe using "Skip linking assemblies" with any of them.

Thanks

Comment: .net core [3.x removed this interface](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/commit/d7a7c65) . post your csproj and all your used nugets

Comment: try to delete obj/bin folder and build the app again.

Comment: in obj folder there is an **project.assets.json**, open it and look which nuget package you use has this dependency , I only see 3.1.2 for me

Comment: @magicandre1981, that's the problem which I knew.
There are two versions of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features (3.1.2 and 2.2.0).
The question is how to remove the 2.2.0 version from the compiled project and the generated project.assets.json file.

Comment: is it listed as direct usage or as a dependency from a nuget package (shown as **"dependencies": {** ) ?

Comment: I appended the lines in project.assets.json file which contains dependencies to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features v. 2.2.0.

Comment: this is wired as you don't reference it. and if you rename the project.assets.json to .bak, you get the same content again?

Comment: Yes, every time it's generated, the file contain references to 2.2.0.

Comment: post the complete csproj (anonymize sensitive data )

Comment: Here's the Pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/60dbefEh, thanks for your time.

Comment: this is the json and still shows that you must have a lot of 2.2.0 packages referenced. Share the csproj file.

Comment: I changed the Pastebin link, check now please.

Comment: this looks fine. Also share the csproj of your shared project

Comment: Here's the shared project:
https://pastebin.com/pc7S14e8

and here's the PLC project:
https://pastebin.com/ica6SWJk

Comment: ok, in shared you reference 2.2.0: **<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />** remove this

Comment: does it work now?

Comment: Thanks for asking, I'm still moving MVC related codes in the Shared project to the MVC project.

Comment: @magicandre1981 it's working fine now. I appreciate your time and suggestions. Thank you VERY much.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer, so that [you can accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to "close" the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message

> error XA2006: Could not resolve reference to
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.Authentication.IAuthenticationHandler'
>   (defined in assembly **'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=2.2.0.0**,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60') with scope
>   '**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features,** Version=**2.2.0.0**, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

and the entry in the project.assets.json:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/2.2.0": {
  "type": "package",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features": "2.2.0",
    "System.Text.Encodings.Web": "4.5.0"
  },
  "compile": {
    "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll": {}
  },
  "runtime": {
    "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll": {}
  }
},
```

shows that you still use an old asp.net core 2.2 reference.

The [shared project](https://pastebin.com/pc7S14e8) shows were it is referenced:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
```

and mixing it with 3.1.2 references

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" Version="3.1.2" />
```

causes your issue.

Remove here the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" entry to fix it.

Comment: I got it now, the MVC Core libraries shouldn't exist or being inherited in Xamarin project because they have version conflict. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks very much, I had a similar problem. tldr - remember to check the csproj files of your shared projects too.